# How to update nested field using POJO in spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch to use elasticsearch as my datasource. I modeled my entity in this way

**Foo.java**

```
@Document(indexName = "foo", shards = 1, versionType = VersionType.INTERNAL, createIndex = true)
public class Foo {

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, name = "bar")
    private Bar bars;
}
```

**Bar.java**

```
public class Bar {

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

I am updating only "bar" value in foo document using UpdateQuery as follows

```
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("bar", bar);
UpdateQuery updateQuery = UpdateQuery.builder(id)
                    .withScript("ctx._source.bar = params.bar")
                    .withParams(params)
                    .build();
            UpdateResponse updateResponse = operations.update(updateQuery, index);
```

I am getting the following error

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot write xcontent for unknown value of type class com.myapp.model.Bar
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.unknownValue(XContentBuilder.java:833) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.map(XContentBuilder.java:895) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.map(XContentBuilder.java:870) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.field(XContentBuilder.java:866) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.script.Script.toXContent(Script.java:660) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.value(XContentBuilder.java:857) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.value(XContentBuilder.java:850) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.field(XContentBuilder.java:842) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
```

Note:
I tried updating a foo.name field using script. It worked fine. the problem is using Bar object in update query.

Any idea to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that Elasticsearch doesn't know how to store and process class `com.myapp.model.Bar` because it's specific for your domain (in contrast with `String`, `Boolean` etc., which are common for all domains).

So you must explicitly tell to Spring and Elasticsearch how to map `com.myapp.model.Bar` to simple types and vice versa: create reading and writing converters and then register them in `ElasticsearchCustomConversions`. See section [6.1.3. Custom Conversions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.conversions) in official documentation for complete example.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention this in my question. I also registered and written reading and writing converter for both Foo and Bar model. But these conveters are not called when I execute updateQuery with script. These converter are called while saving the Foo object using repository.save(foo) method.